# Forking from two repositories

Tags: git, github

I've been working on one project `project_x` and I want to fork from another project `project_y`. But forking from `project_y` keeps send me to the page for `project_x` repository page.

Here is the relation ship between the two projects.

`project_x` is forked from `project_z`.
`project_z` is forked from `project_y`.

I want to fork from `project_y`. But for some reason I couldn't understand, I can't. 
Can any body tell me why forking keeps sending me to `project_x` repository page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be talking about git here, only github. Are you asking about the website?

Comment: Yes @evolutionxbox, but I was thinking this may be related to the way git handles the relationship between git repositories.

Comment: Git doesn't have any other linking mechanism other than remotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you really need to fork `project_y`, delete your fork of `project_x` & fork `project_y`.

**Long Answer:**

By definition, your fork(`project_x`) of a fork(`project_z`) **is** a fork of the original(`project_y`).
When you open a pull request, you get the option to choose both the origin and the destination for your pull request. The choices available there obviously depend on the fork graph, but as long as there is a path in the graph between the 2 repositories, you should be safe.
Also, since pull requests live on the website side, you don't even need to add a remote as long as you don't want to use it from git.

Now, of course, you might want to reconsider your place in that graph, and make yourself a direct child of the real upstream, but that's mostly unrelated.

There is a twisted way to have multiple forks, which is to create organizations and fork in them. That way you can "own" multiple repositories in the same graph. But there's really no need to go there.